# Activity indicator won't finish action

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uicollectionview, uiactivityindicatorview

I have an activity indicator that stops once reading from Firebase is done.

If I have a user with products added, the indicator finishes fine. Alas, if a user who did not upload any products tries to see his, the indicator won't finish its action.

My code :

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{

    AddProductImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PLUS")

    let singlePlusTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("AddProductTapDetected"))
    AddProductImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    AddProductImage.addGestureRecognizer(singlePlusTap)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.MyProductsCollection.delegate = self
    self.MyProductsCollection.dataSource = self;


    // create a hover view that covers all screen with opacity 0.4 to show a waiting action
    let fadeView:UIView = UIView()
    fadeView.frame = self.view.frame
    fadeView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    fadeView.alpha = 0.4

    // add fade view to main view
    self.view.addSubview(fadeView)
    // add activity to main view
    self.view.addSubview(activityView)
    activityView.hidesWhenStopped = true
    activityView.center = self.view.center
    // start animating activity view
    activityView.startAnimating()

    self.ref = Database.database().reference()
    let loggedOnUserID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid


    if let currentUserID = loggedOnUserID
    {
        // Retrieve the products and listen for changes
         self.ref?.child("Users").child(currentUserID).child("Products").observe(.childAdded, with:
            { (snapshot) in

                // Code to execute when new product is added
                let prodValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                let prodName = prodValue?["Name"] as? String ?? ""
                let prodPrice = prodValue?["Price"] as? Double ?? -1
                let prodDesc = prodValue?["Description"] as? String ?? ""
                let prodURLS = prodValue?["MainImage"] as? String
                let prodAmount = prodValue?["Amount"] as? Int ?? 0
                let prodID = snapshot.key

                let prodToAddToView = Product(name: prodName, price: prodPrice, currency: "NIS", description: prodDesc, location: "IL",
                                              toSell: false, toBuy: false, owner: currentUserID, uniqueID: prodID, amount: prodAmount, mainImageURL: prodURLS)


                self.products.append(prodToAddToView)
                DispatchQueue.main.async
                    {
                        self.MyProductsCollection.reloadData()
                        // remove the hover view as now we have data
                        fadeView.removeFromSuperview()
                        // stop animating the activity
                        self.activityView.stopAnimating()
                }
        }
        ) // Closes observe function
    }
    super.viewDidLoad()

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.childAdded` event only fires when there is a child. So as you noted: if there may be no children, you can't use `.childAdded` to hide the activity indicator.

The only event that is guaranteed to fire is `.value`, so you'll want to use that to detect the condition:

```
let ref = self.ref?.child("Users").child(currentUserID).child("Products")
ref.observe(.value, with:
        { (snapshot) in
    self.activityView.stopAnimating()
})
```

If you do this, you'll get the child nodes in this handler anyway. So you may also consider looping through the child nodes of the `snapshot` and handling them here:

```
ref.observe(.value, with:
        { (snapshot) in
    self.activityView.stopAnimating()
    for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as [FIRDataSnapshot] {
       ...
    }
})
```

Comment: I want the animation to stop once all items have been loaded. In this solution, it stops before they are loaded. Correct ?

Comment: `.value` fires after all children have been loaded. Give it a try.

Comment: Which one? First or second suggestion ?

Comment: I tried the first suggestion! While the activity indicator does finish, it seems to be creating a product (It enters the with: part of the value even tho there's none)

Comment: Btw, I tried implementing your second suggestion and itgave a couple of errors. "'[Any]' is not convertible to '[DataSnapshot]'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?"

Comment: Yeah, that could indeed be. Since `snapshot.children` are guaranteed to be `FIRDataSnapshot` that downcast is safe.